# Custom theme for Tumblr: search doesn't work

Tags: themes, tumblr

How can I show search results in my Tumblr theme?

The form:

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="{SearchQuery}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

The markup:

```
{block:SearchPage}
????
{/block:SearchPage}
```

I tried several different variations of this code bot it simply doesn't return any results:

```
{block:Posts}
   {block:SearchPage}
      {SearchResultCount}
      {Title}                
   {/block:SearchPage}
....
{/block:Posts}
```

Comment: The `{block:SearchPage}` block needs to be outside of the posts block. That's one problem. Search pages are treated like index pages for displaying posts.

Comment: iirc, Tumblr search (theme operator) only looks at tags, not content.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{block:SearchPage}
  <div class="result">
    <p>{lang:Found SearchResultCount results for SearchQuery 2}</p>
    {block:NoSearchResults}<p>{lang:No results for SearchQuery 2}</p>{/block:NoSearchResults}
  </div>
{/block:SearchPage}
```

It must absolutely be outside the Posts block. If you're still having trouble try skimming through a starter theme I've worked on found here. http://git.io/hA6dBA